# How can I connect a kinect to my raspberry pi

Tags: usb, usb-power

The kinect plug looks close to USB but it's not quite the same. How do I get this to plug into my rpi? Do I need to cut the plug type and attach a regular usb plug instead?

I've looked for a walkthrough regarding this but I haven't been about to find one that covers the physical connection. Please let me know if you know of a good walk through.

Comment: Kinect V1 or V2?

Comment: there is a guide here http://www.instructables.com/id/Wiring-an-Xbox-Kinect-for-USB/?ALLSTEPS I would guess that ebay would be able to sell you an adaptor

Comment: @Aphire The one for the xbox 360, I assume that's v1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the link listed in the comments above, which will help you convert the plug to a proper USB plug, you'll also need drivers for the Kinect sensor.

Check out this project for a small embedded driver:  https://github.com/xxorde/librekinect

and look at this question as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743479/raspberry-pi-with-Kinect

Comment: After looking at some of these links I found a connector adapter at http://www.amazon.com/Xbox-360-Kinect-Adapter-Power-Supply/dp/B004IXRXGY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1308269162&sr=8-1